# WPF MVVM dispose ViewModel when UC unload

Tags: user-controls, viewmodel, mvvm-light, dispose

i start building a WPF application, with MVVM-Light. My App have a top menu bar and a left menu bar with a central panel with some user controls show with left/top menu options. Everything go fine but my view model don't cleanup/dispose; when i select a menu option from left or top menu, my viewmodel stil exists and when i come back into menu option, the view don't refresh and maintain insert value.

Here a semple of my code:

MainViewModel receive message from top/left menu and show UserControl

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
       Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage<string>>(this, "My_Token", (message) =>
        {MessageUtility wMesageUtility = new MessageUtility();
            switch (message.Notification)
            {
                case "MyMessage":
                    switch (message.Content)
                    {
                        case "Insert":
                            if (!SimpleIoc.Default.IsRegistered<Insert_ViewModel>())
                            {
                                SimpleIoc.Default.Register<Insert_ViewModel>(true);
                            }

                            wInsertVM = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<Insert_ViewModel>();
                            ShowMainView(null);
                            CurrentViewModel = wInsertVM;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
```

My ViewModel Class:

```
public class Insert_ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public FormInternal_ViewModel()
    {
       ...Some Code with ICommand and private methods
    }
}
```

My XAML file:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.UC.Insert"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"              
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
         xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="700"             
         >
<DockPanel Name="MainDock" LastChildFill="True" DataContext="{Binding Insert, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
           Height="Auto">

    <Grid>
   </Grid>
 </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

How can i dispose Insert_ViewModel when top/left menu are selected?
Thanks.